# Connect to MS Access Database with android

Tags: c#, android, ms-access, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a project and I need to connect to MS Access Database. The problem is that I'm using a pretty new platform , I'm using Visual Studio 2015 `Xamarin` and I'm developing to android with c# (thought this platform). 
I already have a project with this Database using aspx and i need to connect the android application to this Database .
I could not find any answer for it , probably cause it's new .
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you intend to host the database on the android device itself? I highly doubt there is support for MS Access on android.

Comment: I just want the application to use it , I'm not going to upload it or something , it's a project for school and I need to use the 4 sql commands (select , delete , insert and update) through the android project . 
By the way , I'm also not sure that I can do it but I develop to android through visual studio 2015 , so there might be a way to do it .
By the way 2 (:D) , i saw that people can do it through android studio .

Comment: I expect others that use MS Access expose it with a service running on the Internet, they do not run it directly on the android. Databases can't just run anywhere, there must be drivers for it. You will have to switch your database to something supported like SqlLite.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related only to Xamarin or MS Access. 
Everytime you want to use the same database in different applications (in your case a website and mobile apps), it is better to create a new layer (WCF Service or REST API) in order to access the same database on the server. This is more flexible and would be the right thing in your case.

Without moving the architecture to the next Level, you will always have such problems when mixing old and new technologies together.

If you just want to finish this quickly for school and use the database only on the device, then there is no way to use the MS Access database with xamarin. I recommend using SQL lite for this and there are lots of examples for that:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

It not clear if the database is to run “local” on the android, or you just wishing to connect to some web service that holds the database?

If you needing a local database to run 100% stand-alone on the Android device, then Access is not supported. Your best bet for a local database would thus be SQLite.

Perhaps you don’t need nor want a local data store. In this case if the Access database is on the server, then you would be forced to write some kind of web service to “interact” with your Android software and the web server (this would not be a "general" interface to the database, but a set of web services that you expose on the web site - this assumes you thus have control and are able to write software and implement a web service on the web site. So in this case some kind of “direct” connection to the Access database is not possible.

You could again certainly DIRECTLY connect to a server based database like SQL server – but this would assume the web hosting allows external ODBC connections to the database (often they don’t allow this, but some do).

So not clear is if you need a local database running on the Android that can THEN connect to some web or server based system, or you simply want the android to connect via the internet to some database hosted on some server and the Android device does not have a local database at all.

Regardless of the location of MSAccess, you cannot "connect" to a non server database like Access. So the question remains as to "where" you want this database to be used, and ALSO if you need a local data store on the Android device or not.